# How to make pd.MultiIndex merge column index vertically?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

(My first post, very excited! Happy Wednesday!)

When I use `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` and `pd.ExcelWriter` to create an Excel file, the column index looks like the following:

[image]

`col_index2` is being merged, but not `col_index1`.

It seems `pd.MultiIndex` can automatically merge column index horizontally but not vertically

Is there a way to fix this? I  must have overlooked something obvious

Also, does anyone know why there is an empty row after the column index?

Any help is truly appreciated! Thank you guys so much!

```py
import pandas as pd
tuples = [('col_index1', 'col_index1'), ('col_index2', 'col_index3'), ('col_index2', 'col_index4')]
col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
row_index = ['row_index1']
df = pd.DataFrame(index = row_index, columns = col_index)
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can clean up the tuples before making them headers to remove duplicates

Fast ordered list reduction: [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016257/4541045)

```py
tuples = [('col_index1', 'col_index1'), ('col_index2', 'col_index3'), ('col_index2', 'col_index4')]
tuples = [tuple(dict.fromkeys(t).keys()) for t in tuples]
# [('col_index1',), ('col_index2', 'col_index3'), ('col_index2', 'col_index4')]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in my quick test.
When change ('col_index1', 'col_index1') to ('col_index1',), it actually becomes ('col_index1', 'col_index4').
But thank you for your answer!

Comment: This is late but allow me to accept this answer. Once again, many thanks!